# Find decimal in string and leave the rest

Tags: regex

I have a log file that prints request times, e.g.

> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.1 ms
>
> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.2 ms
>
> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO GOOD BYE WORlD: 224.3 ms
>
> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.4 ms

I want to strip out lines with HELLO WORlD but only print the ms timing. I will then paste the results into excel an get the total/average, etc.

grep 'HELLO WORlD' myFile.txt will give me:

> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.1 ms
>
> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.2 ms
>
> 2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 224.4 ms

But I want:

> 224.1 ms
>
> 224.2 ms
>
> 224.4 ms

Or

> 224.1
>
> 224.2
>
> 224.4

(?<=HELLO WORlD: )(?s)(.*$) but it gives me everything after 'HELLO WORlD:' on the matched line plus the rest of the entire document. Plus I cannot get it to work with:

```
grep 'HELLO WORlD' myFile.txt | grep (?<=HELLO WORlD: )(?s)(.*$)
```

Comment: Instead of `.*` you could use `[0-9]+[.][0-9]+` to capture only the decimal with a mandatory fractional part.

Comment: Read the manual for `grep` might be a good first start.

Comment: Try [`(?<=HELLO WORlD: )\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/beQzlO/1) or  `(?<=HELLO WORlD: )\d+(?:\.\d+)? ms`

Comment: Which language?

Comment: environment? linux or windows? are we allowed to use `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it **very** simple and stick to grep, you can use the `-o` (`--only-matching`) option.

For example, `grep -o '...$` will output the last three characters. In your case this would give you the desired result.

```
grep 'HELLO WORlD' myFile.txt | grep -o '........$'

224.1 ms
224.2 ms
224.4 ms
```

Comment: `grep -o '........$'` is amazing hack. If input is `2018-02-14 14:11:27,596 INFO HELLO WORlD: 4 ms` it will give output as `lD: 4 ms`

Comment: Yes, this is just a **very** simple solution with zero flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `awk` is available to you since you are using `grep` for searching log file.

It is pretty easy using `awk`:

```
awk '/HELLO WORlD/{print $(NF-1)}' file.log
```

```
224.1
224.2
224.4
```

Alternatively using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'HELLO WORlD:\h+\K[\d.]+' file.log
```

```
224.1
224.2
224.4
```

Answer (score 0):

With ***cut*** + ***grep*** solution:

```
grep "HELLO WORlD"  Input_file | cut -d" " -f6
```

Output will be as follows:

```
224.1
224.2
224.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-o` option; to get only the digits followed by the characters `ms`

You can try

`grep 'HELLO WORlD' myFile.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*.[0-9]* ms$'`

Tried for various inputs

[image]